# Какой GUI-модуль использовать для разработки игр

Tags: python, разработка-игр, gui, python-2.x

Какой кроссплатформенный GUI-модуль использовать для разработки простой игр.

В первую очередь интересуют стандартные GUI-модули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбрал wxPython, т.к. кроссплатформенный и на перспективу - с поддержкой GL.

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел в файле: [Python. Лекция 12. Создание приложений с
GUI.](http://ideafix.name/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Python-12.pdf)

(далее выдержка из файла)

Следующий  список  далеко  не  полон,  но  отражает  многообразие существующих решений:

1. **Tkinter.**
   Многоплатформенный пакет имеет хорошее управление расположением компонентов. Интерфейс выглядит одинаково на различных платформах (Unix, Windows,  Macintosh).  Входит  в  стандартную  поставку  Python.  В  качестве документации  можно  использовать  руководство  "An  Introduction  to  Tkinter" ("Введение     в     Tkinter"),     написанное     Фредриком     Лундом: http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/
2. **wxPython.**
   Построен  на  многоплатформной  библиотеке  wxWidgets  (раньше называлась  wxWindows).  Выглядит  родным  для  всех  платформ,  активно совершенствуется,  осуществлена  поддержка  GL.  Имеется  для  всех  основных
   платформ.  Возможно,  займет  место  Tkinter  в  будущих  версиях  Python.  Сайт: http://www.wxpython.org/
3. **PyGTK.**
   Набор  визуальных  компонентов  для  GTK+  и  Gnome.  Только  для
   платформы GTK.
4. **PyQT/PyKDE.**
   Хорошие пакеты для тех, кто использует Qt (под UNIX или Windows) или KDE.
5. **Pythonwin.**
   Построен  вокруг  MFC,  поставляется  вместе  с  оболочкой  в  пакете
   win32all; только для Windows.
6. **pyFLTK.**
   Аналог  Xforms,  поддержка  OpenGL.  Имеется  для  платформ  Windows  и
   Unix. Сайт: http://pyfltk.sourceforge.net/
7. **AWT, JFC, Swing.**
   Поставляется вместе с Jython, а для Jython доступны средства, которые использует Java. Поддерживает платформу Java.
8. **anygui.**
   Независимый  от  нижележащей  платформы  пакет  для  построения графического    интерфейса    для    программ    на    Python.    Сайт:
   http://anygui.sourceforge.net/
9. **PythonCard.**
   Построитель  графического  интерфейса,  сходный  по  идеологии  с
   HyperCard/MetaCard.    Разработан    на    базе wxPython.    Сайт: http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/

Список актуальных ссылок на различные графические библиотеки, доступные из
Python, можно найти по следующему адресу: http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.python/python_GUI.html